# How to call a non action method by clicking a button in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

How to call a non action method by clicking a button in MVC

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("GenerateError", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "submitForm" }))
{
     <button type="submit" id="btnSubmit" name="Command" value="Submit">Generate Error</button> 
}
```

Now, what if GenerateError is an non action method. How can we call [NonAction] methods using button click

Comment: If you want to invoke the method as an action method (ie. have it called when you click a button), why are you marking it with `NonActionAttribute`?

Comment: And why do you need it?

Comment: it is just to demo error capture facility....you can say this method just contains 1/0 which will throw an error divisible by zero.....what do you suggest....?

Comment: @anilpurswani That still doesn't explain why you are marking the method with `NonActionAttribute`.

Comment: Create an action method that throws...anything else is probably outside the MVC model.

Comment: @Jez  we have some ActionMethods which are calling some other methods which may/may not throw an error.....so for demo I had added one Button in Index page for demo to show how non captured errors will be treated in our application.....So clicking the GenerateError Button it should throw an error....Do you think adding ActionMethod for this is fine.....

Comment: @anil Yeah in that case I guess just create a wrapper action method that calls the non-action method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an action wrapper for `GenerateError` and use it

EDITED:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("GenerateErrorWrapper", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "submitForm" }))
{
     <button type="submit" id="btnSubmit" name="Command" value="Submit">Generate Error</button> 
}
```

Your NonActionMethod:

```
[NonActionMethod]
public void NonActionMethod()
{
    ...
}
```

Your action wrapper:

```
public ActionResult View()
{
    NonActionMethod();
}
```

I just can't understand why do you need it

Answer (score 0):

You can make ajax request to URL {controller}/{your_non-action_method} if that does not marked with NonActionAttribute.

Comment: any public method not marked as NonActionAttribute is bydefault treated as Action method

Comment: Purpose of NonActionAttribute is to restrict access to this method. Or you need to make it as Action Method or you need to make another method wrapper as Alex Ovechkin suggested

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Jquery `$.post` or `$.ajax` to check the status or any thing else.

Comment: No you can simply return the simple string. And get that string in $.post or $.ajax and adjust it accordingly.